Selenium issue: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist (SessionNotCreated)
since a week ago, we are facing an error when we start the ChromeDriver in a Selenium project. Our C# piece of code is:
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
options.AddArguments("--lang=en-GB");
options.AddArgument("--disable-gpu");
options.AddArgument("--window-size=1920,1080");

options.AddArgument("--incognito");
options.AddArgument("--disable-dev-shm-usage");

driver = new ChromeDriver(
    new DriverManager().SetUpDriver(new ChromeConfig(), VersionResolveStrategy.MatchingBrowser),
    options,
    TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3));


The chrome browser version is 125.0.6422.142.
We are receiving the following error:
System.InvalidOperationException : session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist (SessionNotCreated)
We have tried many different paths adding and deleting options without success:

Install older Chrome version.

Install older Selenium versions.

Install older Visual Studio Version.

Run solution with Admin permission.

Headless mode.

no sandbox argument.

--remote-debugging-pipe.

--remote-debugging-port=9222.

--user-data-dir=C:/path/to/Chrome/Userdata.


Even so, we are not being able to unblock the situation.

did the browser launch?  (or launch and then crash?)  The error is telling you the browser did not drop the file that the webdriver reads to determine the port/sessionID for communication with the browser.

The browser launched but with this URL "data:,". After the commandTimelog defined, it crashes with that error.

check your chromedriver version... if the major versions match you should be good there.  Also check with no chrome options set.  A bad option can sometimes cause a crash.  Check Selenium version.  In the new version you won't need the drivermanager as it's built-in.  Just use simple case to debug:  IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();  If you find the options were the issue, add them back one at a time to see which might be causing the crash.
